# Flutter env.g.dart file not generated

Tags: flutter

In my flutter app I have an .env file in the root path of the application. In lib/env there is an env.dart file like following

```
import 'package:envied/envied.dart';

part 'env.g.dart';

@Envied(path: '.env')
abstract class Env {
  @EnviedField(varName: 'BASE_URL_VOADMIN', obfuscate: true)
  static final String baseUrlVoadmin = _Env.baseUrlVoadmin;
  @EnviedField(varName: 'VOOTA_APP_USERNAME', obfuscate: true)
  static final String vootaAppUsername = _Env.vootaAppUsername;
  @EnviedField(varName: 'VOOTA_APP_PASSWORD', obfuscate: true)
  static final String vootaAppPassword = _Env.vootaAppPassword;
}
```

Running following commands does not generate an error, but the env.g.dart file is not generated neither.

- flutter clean,
- flutter pub get
- flutter pub run build_runner build

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Do you use the latest version of the package? I have similar setup and it works fine, I use `envied: ^0.3.0+3`. Also you need `envied_generator` under `dev_dependencies` in `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: I had envied: 0.3.0+3 and envied_generator: 0.3.0. Moving envied_generator to 0.3.0+3 solved the problem. Thank you

Comment: Does not work for me: Because envied_generator >=0.3.0+3 depends on analyzer ^5.1.0 and riverpod_generator 2.2.5 depends on analyzer ^6.0.0, envied_generator >=0.3.0+3 is incompatible with riverpod_generator 2.2.5.
And because no versions of riverpod_generator match >2.2.5 <3.0.0, envied_generator >=0.3.0+3 is incompatible with riverpod_generator ^2.2.5